# Server 2008 R2 not responding to ping, RDP, port 80, etc

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, webserver, ping

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 Domain Controller. I can RDP, ping, and access the webserver while in the local area network on the LAN NIC. But I cannot RDP, ping, or access the webserver while outside the network.

If I restart the server, however, I can do all 3 for a small period of time (about 2-3 minutes). After that, the server no longer responds to any requests.

I have made sure that all the correct ports are open and have even tried turning of the firewall: no luck.

Why would requests from the WAN not work while requests from the LAN are?

Comment: Actually, VPN connection requests to the WAN work, but nothing else.

Comment: Does your service provider have port blocking in place?  My theory goes like this, you get a new IP address when you shut off/turn back on the server, and it takes a minute for the network to engage port blocking for the new address (by using an IDS).  Trying to use multiple different ports over a short period of time (a few minutes) may look like a scan and cause the system to defend your server.  Or I'm completely wrong and it's internet gremlins.

Comment: Another option would be DNS configuration issue, unless you're doing everything by IP address (you don't mention either one).

Comment: The server operates on our University's network and has a static IP. The server is re-installed every semester and this is the first time I have had an issue like this. Could be DNS, as active directory automatically configures a DNS server. I don't know a lot about DNS though, so that may very well be where my issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the conversation above I'd say check your DNS configuration.

Comment: Can you expand upon your answer?

Comment: @DragonLord - Not without knowing Devin's entire DNS and Active Directory configuration.  Note in the comments above I state that this symptom could be indicative of a DNS problem, and Devin mentions he's going to check it.

Comment: @Everett I'm not sure where to begin with the DNS server. I'm currently looking through some documentation on how to set up the DNS server and hoping that I find a bit of information or a step that I missed.